# Recaptcha false positive -Users access resources via Citrix on a virtual PC or published app. When working sites using recaptcha we are always flagged

Tags: recaptcha

Our company does business with a number of sites who have implemented recaptcha and now experience behavior where they must solve many puzzles only to still be flagged as a bot.  All of our users access resources published in a virtual desktop or app catalog and our user/host density is pretty high.  We need to be able to conduct business without being misidentified due to our infrastructure choices...
Are there any options to help?

Users have cleared web cache, and tried the site from private browsers.  From an IT perspective, we have migrated their sessions to other virtual hosts.  We have no control over the IP's assigned to the virtual hosts in Azure.